# AWS CodeCommit - list specific repositories

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, policy, aws-codecommit

I am currently trying to configure an AWS policy for CodeCommit so that only one specific repo is shown on the repository overview page in the AWS GUI.

Currently my policy looks like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "codecommit:Merge*",
            "codecommit:Post*",
            "codecommit:Describe*",
            "codecommit:Update*",
            "codecommit:Get*",
            "codecommit:Test*",
            "codecommit:BatchGet*",
            "codecommit:GitPull",
            "codecommit:Create*",
            "codecommit:Put*",
            "codecommit:GitPush",
            "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
            "codecommit:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-central-1:12345678:mycompany.drupal.myrepo.website"
    }
]
```

}

But on the overview page I am always running into this error:

```
Error
User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/myuser@mycompany.de is not authorized to perform: codecommit:ListRepositories
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way for you to do this right now. ListRepositories in CodeCommit will not filter results by authorization, this is a common pattern across many AWS services' List APIs.

Answer (score 1):

**AWS ListRepositories** does not support resource-level permissions. This requires a wildcard (*) for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your policy is too restrictive for the AWS system being referenced ie CodeCommit. It may require `List*` and/or `Describe*`permissions to all repos, in order to perform its basic functions, such generating a list of all current repositories in the account, as it does on the overview page.

As a test, give `codecommit:List*` and `codecommit:Describe*` permissions to `Resource: "*"` only, as a second policy statement, leaving the more restrictive permissions referencing the specific resource as the first statement:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "RestrictCodeCommitAccessToSingleRepo",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "codecommit:Merge*",
            "codecommit:Post*",
            "codecommit:Update*",
            "codecommit:Get*",          
            "codecommit:Test*",
            "codecommit:BatchGet*",
            "codecommit:GitPull",
            "codecommit:Create*",
            "codecommit:Put*",
            "codecommit:GitPush",
            "codecommit:DeleteBranch"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-central-1:12345678:mycompany.drupal.myrepo.website"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowBasicCodeCommitAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "codecommit:Describe*",
            "codecommit:List*"  
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-central-1:12345678:*"    
    }
]
```

I know this does not meet your objective of listing only the specific repo authorized, but you will still have denied all `Create*`,`Put*`,`Update*` etc type operations to all other repos. That should meet the main security objective of restricting R/W access to all other repos except  `mycompany.drupal.myrepo.website`.

In my permission setups for users/groups, I often allow base operations like `Get*` `List*` `Describe*` for users to allow basic operations in the AWS console to function, even if I am more restrictive with one or more of those resources.

Comment: Yep that is a workaround but actually not what I need. We have different customers that should not be allowed to see each other repositories.

Comment: You may not be able to do that. The AWS console requires those base permissions to function. You may need to have a separate account for each customer.